# How to set HTTP proxy settings on Jelly Bean 4.1.1 on Galaxy SIII LTE

Tags: proxy

I have a Samsung Galaxy SIII LTE (I9305) and I have set up my wifi to connect to my network at work, however I require a username and password in order to access the internet as all our traffic runs through a proxy server. 
There appears to be no such functionality existing in the OS, so please let me know which app I can safely use (without rooting my phone) in order to input a proxy username and password so that I can access the interwebs. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked with the proxy settings in *Settings->Wireless & Networks* (long-press the WiFi APN, check the "Advanced" checkbox)?

Comment: @Izzy: there no fields for the username and password.

Comment: No need: use `user:password@server` for the server address, should work (of course, replace "user" with your username, "password" with your password, and "server" with the real server name/address).

Comment: @Izzy: Are you sure that this with user:password@server is working?

Comment: I don't know if that works on each and every Android version/implementation. But you will know whether it works for you once you tried it. What to lose? I know of cases where it worked, and at least had no negative response since -- but that doesn't make it safe enough to announce "it works everywhere and in any case" (which is why I made it a comment and not an answer :)